# Hard Drive malfunctioning

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Here are some linux reports:

```
smartctl 6.0 2012-10-10 r3643 [i686-linux-3.5.6-pmagic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     FUJITSU MHZ2400BT G1
Serial Number:    K70BT8A26WYY
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00000e 042d71c8f
Firmware Version: 0041000C
User Capacity:    400,088,457,216 bytes [400 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 3f
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.5, 1.5 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Mon Jun 20 20:38:21 2016 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
          was never started.
          Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 121) The previous self-test completed having
          the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 2208) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
          Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
          Suspend Offline collection upon new
          command.
          Offline surface scan supported.
          Self-test supported.
          Conveyance Self-test supported.
          Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
          power-saving mode.
          Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
          General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 254) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003f) SCT Status supported.
          SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
          SCT Feature Control supported.
          SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   100   100   046    Pre-fail  Always       -       10922
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   030    Pre-fail  Offline      -       109576192
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   100   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       5655
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       0 (2000 0)
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   100   100   047    Pre-fail  Always       -       3240
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   019    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   087   087   000    Old_age   Always       -       6620
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   020    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4088
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       263
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       36439
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       36 (Min/Max 8/46)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 (0 6966)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   099   099   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x000f   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       18108
203 Run_Out_Cancel          0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3728033905769
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 492 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
  CR = Command Register [HEX]
  FR = Features Register [HEX]
  SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
  SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
  CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
  CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
  DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
  DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
  ER = Error register [HEX]
  ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 492 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6619 hours (275 days + 19 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 8b 3a 7d ec 40  Error: WP at LBA = 0x00ec7d3a = 15498554

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 01 10 d8 1c 79 40 00      00:38:57.160  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 c0 8a ec 40 00      00:38:57.154  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 00 c0 89 ec 40 00      00:38:57.154  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 f8 c0 88 ec 40 00      00:38:57.154  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 f0 c0 87 ec 40 00      00:38:57.154  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 491 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6619 hours (275 days + 19 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 83 9b 7c 2d 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x002d7c9b = 2981019

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 80 80 20 7c 2d 40 00      00:38:50.809  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 40 00      00:38:50.668  READ LOG EXT
  61 00 78 50 6f ec 40 00      00:38:44.296  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 70 50 6e ec 40 00      00:38:44.296  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 68 50 6d ec 40 00      00:38:44.296  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 490 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6619 hours (275 days + 19 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 0b ca 71 ec 40  Error: WP at LBA = 0x00ec71ca = 15495626

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 00 78 50 6f ec 40 00      00:38:44.296  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 70 50 6e ec 40 00      00:38:44.296  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 68 50 6d ec 40 00      00:38:44.296  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 60 50 6c ec 40 00      00:38:44.296  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 58 50 6b ec 40 00      00:38:44.296  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 489 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6619 hours (275 days + 19 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 3b 99 7c 2d 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x002d7c99 = 2981017

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 80 48 20 7c 2d 40 00      00:33:40.890  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 40 20 7b 2d 40 00      00:33:40.890  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 38 20 7a 2d 40 00      00:33:40.890  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 30 38 0b cc 40 00      00:33:40.890  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 28 00 53 c9 40 00      00:33:40.889  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 488 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6619 hours (275 days + 19 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 0b b7 f5 ed 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00edf5b7 = 15594935

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 c8 18 78 ef 40 00      01:05:23.909  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 c0 c8 37 f2 40 00      01:05:23.874  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 b8 c0 ca ef 40 00      01:05:23.848  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 b0 f0 51 ea 40 00      01:05:23.816  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 a8 f0 50 ea 40 00      01:05:23.816  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      6620         590183579
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      6619         590183579
# 3  Conveyance offline  Completed: read failure       90%      6619         590183579
# 4  Conveyance offline  Completed: read failure       90%      6585         590183579

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I have a hard drive. I was trying to defragment it, and 1st time Windows 7's cursor froze and everything else went black and the second time it got a blue screen (I don't know what the code was). There is basically no more information to give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have bad sectors on your hard drive.

From an Administrative command prompt:
**chkdsk /R c:**

Say **yes** to do this on the next reboot.  Wait until you have hours to spare and reboot and let the test run.  Maybe just before you go to bed.